# Rolling 2 dice desirable amount of time and print out percentages

Tags: arrays, function, dice

I have a task to do a program that rolls 2 dices x amount of times and then print out the result for each number (2-12). This is how far I've come, but as you can see I am stuck. I don't know how to get the array from the throw_dice function to the print_result function. Nor do I know how to calculate and print out the actual percentages of each individual number. I am not asking for someone to complete the code for me, but some tips!

Thnx in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int array[11];
int count=0;

int get_no_of_throws()
{
    int throws;
    printf("How many throws? ");
    scanf("%i", &throws);
    return throws;
}

int throw_dice(int throws)
{
    int dice1;
    int dice2;
    int sum=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(count=0;count<11;count++)
    {
        array[count]=0;
    }
    for(count=0;count<throws; count++)
    {
        dice1=rand()%6+1;
        dice2=rand()%6+1;
        sum=dice1+dice2;
        ++array[count];
    }
    return array[count];
}

void print_results(array)
{
    ?????
}

int main()
{
    int throws;
    get_no_of_throws();
    throw_dice(throws);
    print_results(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will receive a _lot_ more reviews if you tagged this "C" - maybe too many.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sum as the array index.

```
dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
sum = dice1 + dice2;
array[sum-2]++;
```

To print, loop through the array and ...

```
printf("%d %0.1f%%\m", count + 2, array[count]*100.0/throws);
```

Nice touch to consider adding:  Print the percentage of the *expected* results.  Also someplace print `throws`.

Check input result and make sure you return a known value. Current code returns junk if user entered "ABC".  Consider `fgets()/sscanf()`.

```
if (1 != scanf("%i", &throws)) ComplainToUserAboutInput();
```

`return array[count];` is bad.  Simple return 0 or make function return `void`.

Move `int count=0;` in from global to function scope.  I'd move `array` form global to and put it in `main()`, then pass it to various functions.  BTW: consider another name for `array` like dice_occurrence[].  More descriptive than "array".

```
// int count=0;

int throw_dice(int throws) {
  int count;
  ...
  for(count=0; count<11; count++) 
    ...
  for(count=0; count<throws; count++)
    ...
}
```

Minor: Consider making variable more local as in

```
// int dice1;
// int dice2;
// int sum=0;
... 
for(count=0;count<throws; count++)  {
    int dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    int dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    int sum = dice1 + dice2;
    array[sum-2]++;
}
```

Let the space character to be your friend.

```
// dice1=rand()%6+1;
dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
```

`srand(time(NULL));` is good for production.  You may want to comment out during debug to get repeatable results.

Other simplifications or features possible.  For me, I'd create a 6x6 array and just do `dice[rand()%6][rand()%6]++;` then later add up pairs like dice[2][1] and dice[1][2].  One could also assess things like how close are dice[2][1] and dice[1][2] to each other and such.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I will change that in my code and keep thinking about what else I should do to fix it!

Comment: Wow, you really put some time and thought in helping me, really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Jullebaloo Welcome to SO.  Avoid thank-yous  Instead, up-vote answers that were useful (once you get 15+ rep).  After a time (hours to days), if an answer well met your needs, accept the best one.